# How to manually test a data retention requirement in a search functionality?

Tags: testing, manual-testing

Say, data needs to be kept for 2years. Then all data that were created 2years + 1day ago should not be displayed and be deleted from the server. How do you manually test that?

I’m new to testing and I can’t think of any other ways. Also, we cannot do automation due to time constraints.

Comment: Your question is vague on the specifics, but the general approach is to inject the time source so that your test can artificially mock it to be at any point in time, including two years and one day before your test data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the data with backdating of more than two years in the database and can test, if it is being deleted or not automatically, In other ways ,you can change the current business date from the database and can test it

Answer (score 0):

For the data retention functionality a manual tester needs to remember the search data so that the tester can perform the test cases for the search retention feature.
By Taking an example of a social networking app , being a manual tester you need to remember all the users that you searched for recently.

To check the time period of retention you can take the help from the backend developer so that they can change the time period (from like one year to 10 min) for testing purpose.

Even if you delete the search history and then you start typing the already entered search result the related result should pop on the first location of the search result. Data retention policies concern what data should be stored or archived, where that should happen, and for exactly how long. Once the retention time period for a particular data set expires, it can be deleted or moved as historical data to secondary or tertiary storage, depending on the requirement

Answer (score 0):

Let’s us understand with an example, that we have below data in our database table based on past search made by users. Now with the help of this table, you can perform this testing with minimum effort and optimum result. We have Current Date as - **‘2022-03-10’** and Status column states that data is available / not available in database, where Visible means available, while Expired means deleted from table.

| Search Keyword | Search On Date | Search Expiry Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sport | 2022-03-05 | 2024-03-04 | Visible |
| cricket news | 2020-03-10 | 2022-03-09 | Expired - Deleted |
| holy books | 2020-03-11 | 2022-03-10 | Visible |
| dance | 2020-03-12 | 2022-03-11 | Visible |